# Composer on Windows 7 (x64) PHP 5.4.7

Tags: php

I'm not new in composer and PHP I already used it a lot of time on Linux and on Windows too, but today I encountered a problem.

Today I tried to `use composer update / composer install` on my Windows 7 and then I got an exception: "**Composer could not find the config file:**" it is strange, because it was working few days ago.

I tried use the newest composer.phar and also tried use composer installed by Composer-Setup.exe, also I tried put composer.phar on different location (project location etc) it always throwing me the same exception.

When I run composer validate command I've got: *./composer.json is valid*, so composer.json was found and is valid.

Thanks for all answers

Answer (score 0):

delete composer path and variable from enviroment variables and reboot (restart) Windows. Then add variable and path again